# id of the another class in Django

Tags: django

I have 2 models:

```
class Producer(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/prod/%i/" % self.id 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

class Car(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/prod/%s/car/%i" % Producer.id, self.id 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    prod = models.ForeignKey(Producer)
```

On `/sitemap.xml` I have an error: `type object 'Producer' has no attribute 'id'`. How to get in the method `get_absolute_url` (of Car class) `id` of the `Producer`? Thanks. I try `Producer_id`, `Producer__id` but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/prod/%s/car/%s" % (self.prod.id, self.id)
```

Also looking into your code there can be done two more improvements:

1. Model class method should come after the fields
2. You should use [reverse-resolution-of-urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) instead of hard coding the url `/prod/%s/car/%s` which is a bad way to do.